# Call API using Retrofit2 to save and retreive JWT Token

Tags: android, jwt, retrofit2

I have an API for generating guest token

i.e `{{url}}/api/token/guest`

which returns the token as:

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjIxNzc0NTI3OTksImlhdCI6MTs4Xk3x-zFfDg5mhYJO7jM8"}
```

now i want to call the guest token and append in my session so that i can access the data in api

i.e

```
@GET("/api/properties-latest")
Call<Datum> getNewProperties(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

My session class:

```
   public class Session {
    Context context;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private Session session;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    public Session(Context cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = cntx;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }



    public void setJwtToken(String token) {

        prefs.edit().putString("token", token).commit();
    }

    public String getJwtToken() {
        String token = prefs.getString("token", "");
        if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {
            token = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjIxNzc0NTI3OTksImlhdCI6MTUxNjAyMjk5OSwiaXNzIjoiQmFzb2JhYXMgTmVwYWwiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTYwMjI5OTksImp0aSI6Ikd1ZXN0VG9rZW4iLCJzdWIiOjB9.QikmNgBYmqch5HREGFEpUs4Xk3x-zFfDg5mhYJO7jM8";
        }
        return token;
    }
    public String getRefreshToken() {
        String token = prefs.getString("RefreshToken", "");
        if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {
            token = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjIxNzc0NTI3OTksImlhdCI6MTUxNjAyMjk5OSwiaXNzIjoiQmFzb2JhYXMgTmVwYWwiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTYwMjI5OTksImp0aSI6Ikd1ZXN0VG9rZW4iLCJzdWIiOjB9.QikmNgBYmqch5HREGFEpUs4Xk3x-zFfDg5mhYJO7jM8";

        }

        return token;
    }

    public void setRefreshToken(String token) {
        prefs.edit().putString("RefreshToken", token).commit();
    }


}
```

My property method:

```
    property_recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.new_property_recyclerview);
    property_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    property_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    property_recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    listener = this;

    Call<Datum> propertyCall = apiInterface.getNewProperties(session.getJwtToken());
    propertyCall.enqueue(new Callback<Datum>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Datum> call, Response<Datum> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                datum = response.body();

                List<Property> propertyList = datum.getPropertyList();
                propertyAdapter = new PropertyAdapter(propertyList, getContext(), listener);
                property_recyclerView.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Datum> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("New Property Fragment", t.getMessage());
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

I want to access the guest token so that a guest user can see the properties please help me find a solution.

Comment: so whats the issue here?

Comment: issue is that the above token is from postman i want to acces the token through my app

Comment: just hit the postman API from which you are getting the token..from the app itself..via retrofit.. first..

Comment: yes i tried it it dosn't give ma the token

Comment: post the screenshot of post man..along with the **full qualified URL**

Comment: sir please check this link https://prnt.sc/ii6xdm

Comment: what is there in the header ? **application/json** ??

Comment: and also show your retrofit call which you have done for getting the guest token>?

Comment: My interface  @POST("/api/token/guest")
    Call<ResponseBody> getGuestToken();

retrofit call in this link http://prntscr.com/ii730p

Comment: your retrofit call is ok.. just do this.. `token = response.body().get("token");` instead of `token = String.valueOf(response.body());` update if you get the token via the api Call..now

Comment: for getting the token..

Comment: if your token comes in your header then get it like this,     String token = response.headers().get("Authorization");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access `SharedPreference` with `context` like below:

```
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

class MyPref {

    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor spe;
    Context context;

    public MyPref (Context cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = cntx;
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        spe = sp.edit();
    }

    public void setJwtToken(String token) {

        spe.putString("token", token).apply();
    }

    public String getJwtToken() {
        String token = sp.getString("token", "");
        if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {
            token = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjIxNzc0NTI3OTksImlhdCI6MTUxNjAyMjk5OSwiaXNzIjoiQmFzb2JhYXMgTmVwYWwiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTYwMjI5OTksImp0aSI6Ikd1ZXN0VG9rZW4iLCJzdWIiOjB9.QikmNgBYmqch5HREGFEpUs4Xk3x-zFfDg5mhYJO7jM8";
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Now access from your activity like below:

```
MyPref m = new MyPref(this);
String tokenToUse = m.getJwtToken();
```

Now for Retrofit call use it like below:

```
Call<Datum> call = apiInterface.getNewProperties(tokenToUse);
```

Comment: If you find my answer helpful then upvote it and if this is the solution to your question then mark it as a solution.

Comment: import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE; now it shouldn't give you any problem. Also i am editing the answer

Comment: if you have any error then post the stacktrace in your question by editing it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.